# Celery task not detecting error from subprocess

Tags: python, celery

I have the following task with runs a python scripts using Popen (I already tried with check_output, call with the same result)

```
@app.task
def TaskName(filename):
    try:
       proc = subprocess.Popen(['python', filename],stdout=subprocess.PIPE, 
       stderr=subprocess.PIPE): 
       taskoutp, taskerror = proc.communicate()
       print('Output: ', taskoutp)
       print('Error: ', taskerror)
    Except:
       raise Exception('Task error: ', taskerror)
```

If I generate an error in the subprocess it is displayed in the worker cmd window as if it were a normal output/print, the task remains indefinetly with the status 'STARTED' even when I manually close the window opened by the Popen subprocess.

What can I do so the tasks not only prints the error but actually stops and changes its status to FAILURE?

Comment: Try to refactor your code not to use subprocess, but to use [Billard](https://billiard.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) instead (as that is what Celery uses internally).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to store results of your task , you could use this parameter `result_backend` or `CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND` depending on the version of celery you're using.

This parameter can be used for acknowledging a task only after it is processed :

```
task_acks_late
Default: Disabled.

Late ack means the task messages will be acknowledged after the task has been executed, not just before (the default behavior).
```

Complete list of Configuration options can be found here => https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/configuration.html

Comment: I am guessing you have `task_track_started` set - so you get status when STARTED , but you haven't set `task_acks_late` - so once started it just considers the task can be removed from queue . Hence  setting `task_acks_late=True`  might solve your problem.